# How is cross validation implemented?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm currently trying to train a neural network using cross validation, but I'm not sure if I'm getting how cross validation works. I understand the concept, but I can't totally see yet how the concept translates to code implementation. The following is a description of what I've got implemented, which is more-or-less guesswork.

I split the entire data set into K-folds, where 1 fold is the validation set, 1 fold is the testing set, and the data in the remaining folds are dumped into the training set.

Then, I loop K times, each time reassigning the validation and testing sets to other folds. Within each loop, I continuously train the network (update the weights) using only the training set until the error produced by the network meets some threshold. **However, the error that is used to decide when to stop training is produced using the validation set, not the training set.** After training is done, the error is once again produced, but this time using the testing set. This error from the testing set is recorded. **Lastly, all the weights are re-initialized (using the same random number generator used to initialize them originally) or reset in some fashion to undo the learning that was done before moving on to the next set of validation, training, and testing sets.**

Once all K loops finish, the errors recorded in each iteration of the K-loop are averaged.

I have bolded the parts where I'm most confused about. Please let me know if I made any mistakes!

Comment: This question fits more to http://stats.stackexchange.com than to SO since it is no question about programming but statistics.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your implementation of Cross Validation is generally correct. To answer your questions:

> However, the error that is used to decide when to stop training is produced using the validation set, not the training set.

You want to use the error on the validation set because it's reduces  [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). This is the reason you always want to have a validation set. If you would do as you suggested, you could have a lower threshold, your algorithm will achieve a higher training accuracy than validation accuracy. However, this would generalize poorly to the unseen examples in the real world, that which your validation set is supposed to model.

> Lastly, all the weights are re-initialized (using the same random number generator used to initialize them originally) or reset in some fashion to undo the learning that was done before moving on to the next set of validation, training, and testing sets.

The idea behind cross validation is that each iteration is like training the algorithm from scratch. This is desirable since by averaging your validation score, you get a more robust value. It protects against the possibility of a biased validation set.

My only suggestion would be to not use a test set in your cross validation scheme, since your validation set already models unseen examples, a seperate test set during the cross validation is redundant. I would instead split the data into a training and test set before you start cross validation. I would then not touch the test set until you want to gain an objective score for your algorithm.

You could use your cross validation score as an indication of performance on unseen examples, I assume however that you will be choosing parameters on this score, optimizing your model for your training set. Again, the possibility arises this does not generalize well to unseen examples, which is why it is a good practice to keep a seperate unseen test set. Which is only used after you have optimized your algorithm.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification on the redundancy of having both the test and validation sets. I have another question now, if you don't mind: if the weights are reset at the end of each iteration, how should the trained values for those weights be determined post cross-validation? Should I record the weights at the end of each iteration and finally set the weight values to the averages (like I've done with the error?) Or could I set the weights equal to whatever they end up being after training in the last iteration?

Comment: The objective of cross validation is to obtain the best values for your parameters. Once you achieved maximum performance during cross validation you would use those parameters to train a model on a final training dataset, given you are also using early stopping, I would use the test set you should have split of before starting cross validation, saving the model with the lowest error on the test set while training it on the enteir dataset you used for cross validation.